# In the days of slavery, were heterosexual interracial pairings more common with black men and white women, or black women and white men?

Tags: united-states, marriage, race, sex

Of course, the anti miscegenation laws were in place that prohibited interracial marriage, so it must have been something that went on and so was a concern.

On that note, did miscegenation laws mainly prohibit formal marriage, or just sex itself?

But was it more common for these interracial relationships to be between white women and black men (as perhaps seems more common today), or white men and black women (such as with Thomas Jefferson and his well chronicled slave mistresses?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145143/discussion-on-question-by-seeking-answers-in-the-days-of-slavery-were-heterosex); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Understand here that this is asking about statistics and data on the history of the intersection of slavery and rape. That means it is asking for data that's unlikely to have been systematically gathered, a request for others to go snorkeling in one of the sewers of history, and likely to be distressing to some users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: I don't have raw data to support what follows, but I base this on some literature (artistic literature, not historical sources).

Considering:

- The fact that possessing slaves on plantation was a difficult task, and thus mostly started and transmitted by and to men, the "master" of the slaves would be a white man -thus having relation with women
- That women were considered in the culture of that time as "house keepers", seeing them with black men would have been badly perceived

=> The answer to the question is that White men + Black women was more frequent than White women + Black men.

Also, this is what is mostly seen in the literature speaking of that time, either contemporary or not.

Comment: Comments purged as a result of flags; the situation crossed over into the personal.

Comment: [comments are barn cats](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3631/1401) .  I recognize the disorientation.  At some point I need to link the various fragments of policy about comments into a coherent post and apply [tag:site-policy] , but the quick summary is that comments frequently get tagged as unfriendly or unkind. Once the comment stream crosses the line into personal attack, moderators will (if time and valor permit) look for opportunities to prune surgically, but _usually_ comments are so tangled that a purge is the best response.  There is a bit more latitude in chat, but...